# Handlebars variable rendering

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following data in the Handlebars template:

```
var1 : 'John'
var2 : 'Hello {{var1}}'
```

Template looks like:

```
Hello {{var1}}
{{var2}}
```

Result is:

```
Hello John
Hello {{var1}}
```

The question is: Exists some way to setup Handlebars to render {{var1}} inside data and get the following result?

```
Hello John
Hello John
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jiri_Mihal/674fjb9k/).

Comment: The link returns a 404.

Comment: @76484 It works now. I just updated the JSFiddle link.